# How to end searched url with &*

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a searh bar linking up to google.no (norway). when you search for music you get this URL: https://www.google.no/#q=music&*. My question is how i can get the (& *) at the end of a search.

```css
.search {
  border: solid 1px grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" action="http://www.google.no/#q=">
  <input class="search" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

Comment: Note that this is after the `#`, so it's a fragment identifier, which is **after** any path/query/parameters. You'll have to build the URL by other means (Javascript) and then link to it. Or use the regular query version of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot submit to this Google page, because it has an anchor `#` in it. This means, it has not the regular GET format, you would get, if you just submit a form to this URL. You have to calculate the correct URL in JavaScript or on the back-end side.

If you want to create the correct URL with JavaScript, you can use the function `encodeURIComponent(url)` to escape the parameter.

Here is an example:

```js
var searchBox = document.querySelector('.search');
var form = document.querySelector('.form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  var value = searchBox.value;
  var escapedValue = window.encodeURIComponent(value);
  var url = "https://www.google.no/#q=" + escapedValue

  alert(url);
  window.location.href = url;

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form class="form" action="test">
  <input class="search" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```